# Join the multiple tables and insert/update/delete in to single table whenever changes happening in those tables using Debezium postgres connecter

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, debezium, cdc

Let's consider the following example, I need to join the 3 tables data and insert/update/delete into single table whenever changes happening into the any one of the single table.

Previously I wrote one join query to combine 6 tables data and truncate the existing table(student_info_table) data before inserting the records(student_info_table).

`3 tables join:`

`select s.id,s.name,sc.school_name,sc.address from student s inner join student_school_mapping ssm  on s.id = ssm.student_id inner join school sc on sc.id=ssm.school_id;`

`Single table`

`create table student_info_table(id number, student_name varchar, school_name varchar, school_addr varchar)`

For example I want to insert a record into student table, after successful insertion doing the following ones,

`Calling the above join query and prepare the list of studentinfo entity results`

`studentInfoRepo.deleteAll();`

`studentInfoRepo.saveAll(List<StudentInfo>)`

This approach is giving performance bottleneck to my spring boot app.

I am trying to achieve this using Debezium connector. but I dont see any option to combine all the tables and insert into single table.

I saw these options in Debezium, but these are individual tables CDC is happening

`"table.whitelist": "public.student,public.student1"`

**Is there any standard mechanisms in Debezium to handle multiple table joins CDC ?**

Can you suggest me if any other way is having to handle this type of use case ?